# JavaFX support for 64bit requirement on Android

Tags: android, javafx, 64-bit, javafxports

With the 1st of August, new apps and updates are required to include 64 Bit native code, if the app ships with them.

Since there is a native JavaFX renderer bundled within each of this kind of apps, we are affected by this.

The [Android Devloper Blogs](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html) further details this.

As far as I can read from the docs and from example code, the current versions (both 1.x and 2.x) of the `javafx-mobile-plugin` don't ship builds for this.
Is there a timeline we might expect this to be included into the plugin/port?

Comment: Shouldn't this be an issue ticket with the respective project?

Comment: Probably. When you know the exact project where to create it on. BitBucket, GitHub, via groups  gluonhq or javafxports? It's a bit confusing, so I basically created this question as a shout-out to the devs, so they can hopefully point me into the right direction.

Comment: Yes, we are already aware of this, and builds should be ready in time.

Comment: @jpereda thank you for your reply. That's great news!